# Java error out of bounds after adding a Map to game

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Im working on a little game the last couple days and already made a huge progress. Now I have a problem I dont see hoe to fix. It says

```
"Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index 8 out of bounds for length 8 at tileMap.TileMap.draw(TileMap.java:158)
    at gameState.Level1State.draw(Level1State.java:38)
    at gameState.GameStateManager.draw(GameStateManager.java:33)
    at main.GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:102)
    at main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I looked into it like an hour but I saw nothing. Can someone find the mistake causing the error? Edit: I deleted the code where it says no error.

```
GamePanel:

package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import gameState.GameStateManager;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{
    
    // Dimensionen
    public static final int WIDTH  = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE  = 2;
        
    
    
    // game thread
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;
    
    //image
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;
    
    // game state Manager
    private GameStateManager gsm;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT* SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
            
    }
    
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if(thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread.start();
            
        }
        
    }
    public void init() {
        
        image= new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                
        g = (Graphics2D) image.createGraphics();
        
        running = true;
        
        
        gsm = new GameStateManager();
    }
    
    
    public void run() {
        
        init();
        
        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;
        
        
        //game loop
        while(running) {
            
            start = System.nanoTime()
;           
            update();
//line 79:
            draw();
            drawToScreen();
            
            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
            if(wait < 0) wait = 5;
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            }
            catch(Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private void update() {
        gsm.update();
        
    }
    private void draw() {
//line 102:
        gsm.draw(g);
        
    }
    private void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }
    
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent key) {
        
    }
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent key) {
        gsm.keyPressed (key.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent key) {
        gsm.keyReleased(key.getKeyCode());
    }
    
}
```

Menu:

```
package gameState;


import tileMap.Background;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MenuState extends GameState{
    
    
    private Background bg;
    
    
    public int currentChoice = 0;
    private String[] options = {
            "Start",
            "Hilfe",
            "Verlassen"
            
    };
    
    private Color titleColor;
    private Font titleFont;
    
    private Font font;

    
    public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        
        this.gsm = gsm;
        
        try {
            
            bg = new Background("/Hintergünde/bg_v2.gif", 1);
            bg.setVector(-0.1, 0);
            
            titleColor = new Color(200, 0, 0);
            titleFont  = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 28);
            
        font = new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void init () {}
    public void update () {
        bg.update();
    }
    
    public void draw (Graphics2D g) {
        
        //Hintergrund
        bg.draw(g);
        
        //Titel
        g.setColor(titleColor);
        g.setFont(titleFont);
        g.drawString("Fred on the run", 80, 70);
        
        //Menü
        g.setFont(font);
        for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if(i == currentChoice) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else {
                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            }
            g.drawString(options[i], 145, 140 + i * 15);
        }
        
    }
    
    private void select() {
        if(currentChoice == 0) {
            gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL1STATE);
        }
        if(currentChoice == 1) {
            //Hilfe
        }
        if(currentChoice == 2) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    
    public void keyPressed(int k) {
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            select();
        }
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            currentChoice--;
            if(currentChoice == -1) {
                currentChoice = options.length -1;
                
            }
        }
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            currentChoice++;
            if(currentChoice == options.length) {
                    currentChoice = 0;
            }
            
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(int k) {}
    
}
```

Level1Stage:

```
package gameState;


import main.GamePanel;
import tileMap.*;


import java.awt.*;


public class Level1State extends GameState {
    
    private TileMap tileMap;

    public Level1State(GameStateManager gsm) {
        this.gsm = gsm;
        init();
    }
    public void init() {
        tileMap = new TileMap(30);
        tileMap.loadTiles("/Tilesets/grasstileset.gif");
        tileMap.loadMap("/Maps/level1-1.map");
        tileMap.setPosition(0, 0);
        
    }
    public void update() {
        
        
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        
        //clear Screen
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT);
        
        
        //draw tile map
//line 38:
    tileMap.draw(g);
    }
    public void keyPressed(int k) {
        
        
    }
    public void keyReleased(int k) {
        
        
    }
}
```

TileMap:

```
package tileMap;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;


import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import main.GamePanel;




public class TileMap {
    //Position:
    private double x;
    private double y;
    
    //bounds
    private int xmin;
    private int ymin;
    private int xmax;
    private int ymax;
    
    private double tween; 
    
    
    //Karte
    private int[][] map;
    private int tileSize;
    private int numRows;
    private int numCols;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    
    //tileset
    private BufferedImage tileset;
    private int numTilesAcross;
    private Tile[][] tiles;
    
    
    //zeichnen
    private int rowOffset;
    private int colOffset;
    private int numRowsToDraw;
    private int numColsToDraw;
    
    public TileMap(int tileSize) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
        numRowsToDraw = GamePanel.HEIGHT / tileSize +2;
        numColsToDraw = GamePanel.WIDTH / tileSize +2;
        tween = 0.07;
    }
    
    public void loadTiles(String s) {
        
        try {
            
            tileset = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(s));
            numTilesAcross = tileset.getWidth() / tileSize;
            tiles = new Tile[2][numTilesAcross];
            
            
            BufferedImage subimage;
            for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++) {
                subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
                
                tiles[0][col] = new Tile (subimage, Tile.NORMAL);
                subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
                tiles[1] [col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.BLOCKED);
                
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void loadMap(String s) {
        
        try {
            
            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(s);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in)
                    );
                    
            numCols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            numRows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            map = new int[numRows][numCols];
            width  = numCols * tileSize;
            height = numRows * tileSize;
            
            
            String delims = "\\s+";
            for(int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
                for(int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                    map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public int getTileSize() {return tileSize; }
    public int getx() { return (int)x; } 
    public int gety() { return (int)y; } 
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
    
    public int getType(int row, int col) {
        int rc = map [row] [col];
        
        int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
        int c = rc % numTilesAcross;
        return tiles[r] [c].getType();
        
        
    }
    
    public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
            
        this.x += (x - this.x) * tween;
        this.y += (y - this.y) * tween;
        
        fixBounds();
        
        colOffset = (int)-this.x /tileSize;
        rowOffset = (int)-this.y /tileSize;
    }
    
    private void fixBounds() {
        if(x < xmin) x = xmin;
        if(y < ymin) y = ymin;
        if(x > xmax) x = xmax;
        if(y > ymax) x = ymax;
        
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        
        for (int row = rowOffset; row < rowOffset + numRowsToDraw; row++) {
            
        
        for(
            int col = colOffset;
                col < colOffset + numColsToDraw; col++) {
            
            if(col >= numCols) break;
            
        //line 158: 
            if(map[row][col] == 0) continue;
            
            int rc = map[row][col];
            int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
            int c = rc % numTilesAcross;
            
            g.drawImage(tiles[r][c].getImage(),
                    (int)x + col * tileSize,
                    (int)y + row * tileSize, null);
        }   
        }
            
    }
    
}
```

Tile:

```
package tileMap;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;






public class Tile {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int type; 
    
    //tile Typen
    public static final int NORMAL  = 0;
    public static final int BLOCKED = 1;
     
    
    public Tile(BufferedImage image, int type) {
        this.image = image;
        this.type  = type;
        
    }
    
    public BufferedImage getImage() { return image; }
    public  int getType() { return type; }
    
    
}
```

and the last one, the game state manager:

```
package gameState;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GameStateManager {

    private ArrayList <GameState> gameStates;
    private int currentState;
    
    public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
    public static final int LEVEL1STATE = 1;
    
    public GameStateManager() {
        
        gameStates= new ArrayList <GameState>();
        
        currentState = MENUSTATE;
        gameStates.add(new MenuState(this));
        gameStates.add(new Level1State(this));
    }
    
    public void setState(int state) {
        currentState = state;
        gameStates.get(currentState).init();
    }
    
    public void update () {
            gameStates.get(currentState).update();
            
    }
    public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g) {
            gameStates.get(currentState).draw(g);
        
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(int k) {
        gameStates.get(currentState).keyPressed(k);
        
        
    }
    
    public void keyReleased(int k) {
        gameStates.get(currentState).keyReleased(k);
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code but you've left out the most crucial thing: where is the exception's stack trace? Without it we'd have to guess where the error might be. Also, most of that code is probably not relevant to the problem at all. Btw, you might want to read [ask].

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the complete exception stacktrace? Right now, you posted such a wall of code, that nobody will probably bother to scroll through it all without having a clue where to start to look.

Comment: nobody is going to read all that.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Please indicate where line 158 is in TileMap

Comment: So. Sorry I`ve added the exception stack trace. Also I thought the whole code would make it easier to understand. Will fix it now

Comment: In TileMap.draw(), you have a check to make sure that `col` isn't going out of bounds, but not one for `row`.  It's not possible to see where the actual error is since we can't see which line is 158, but I'm guessing that it's `if(map[row][col] == 0) continue;`.  If it was me, I'd put a `println` statement in front of 158, to show `row` and `col`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only take a guess with the info you gave, but I think the issue might lie in the TileMap draw method, specifically at the values of "row". I see the potential for the value of row to be outside the range of your array. Try adding this constraint (same as you did for column) and see if it helps:

```
if(row >= numRows) break;
```